# How can I construct the Contact application title bar

Tags: android

In android 2.0 Contact application, under the 'Favorites' tab, there is a 'Frequently contacted' title bar. Can you please tell me how can I construct that myself?

I would like what is the font size, font color , back ground color that they use.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the source of the Contacts apk from [here](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Contacts.git;a=summary) and see exactly how the Android devs constructed that UI.